# Perform Firestore query in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I want to perform a Firestore query in a JavaScript function, but I'm having some difficulties with promises.

Let's say I want to get the document ID from a user. So I have created this JavaScript function:

```
function getUid(email) {
    db.collection("users").where("email", "==", email)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            return doc.id;
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        return error;
    });
}
```

Now when I call the function `res.send(getUid("user@example.com"))`, it returns `undefined`.

Which is the correct syntax to wait until the Firestore query finsished?

Comment: What is `res` and where are you calling it?

Comment: `res.send` is just for sending a response in Google cloud functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get()` is an async function, so you need to wrap it into an `async` function. Also, you are not returning anything from the `getUid` function - you are just returning inside a `forEach` parameter. If you want to get all `id` from the snapshot, you can use the `map` function.

```
async function getUids(email) {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("users").where("email", "==", email).get();
    const uids = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { return doc.id });
    return uids;
}

exports.yourFunction = functions.http.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const email = // ...
    res.send(await getUids(email));
});
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me! But how do I catch errors with promises?

Comment: If you're using `await`, you can wrap it into a `try-catch` statement. If you're using `Promise.then`, you can add a `.catch` handler after it.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me how to figure out promises.